# Swift MacOS Grab window id of focused window

Tags: swift, macos, window

I have created a menu bar app, and I was wondering if there is a way that I am able to get the window ids of other applications when they are in focus, or being dragged?

Currently I know I can use CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo to gather information on all of the windows, but I was wondering if there was a way to get the specific window id when I click on a window and it is in focus or I drag it.

CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo, but this returns all of my windows, and I would prefer another method of getting the window id, but I can use this too.

```
    let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.excludeDesktopElements, CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenOnly)
    let windowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
    let infoList = windowListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]
```

My expected results is the selected window id of the window I clicked on, is in focus, or dragging.